# iPhone, Where do I have to save user generated files if I want them to stay there after an app Upgrade (new release)? is Documents directory good?

Tags: iphone, upgrade, nsuserdefaults, avaudiorecorder

I have an app that lets user record their own audio.
By now I'm saving those files into Documents directory.
My question is: if I will release a new version of that app, will user recorded files get deleted?

Is there a better place to store user generated audio files?

Should I use NSUserDefaults for data that stay even after app upgrade?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSUserDefaults is used for storing settings (objects of *Key-Value Coding* compliant classes)
Other data such files you should store in Documents folder, wich survive between updates (if you don't delete it yourself, of course :)

Answer (score 1):

Both the Documents directory and NSUserDefaults survive application updates. Choosing which to use depends on the kind of your data.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, can you point me to some documentation? just to have deeper knowledge. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> if I will release a new version of that app, will user recorded files get deleted?

No.

> Is there a better place to store user generated audio files?

No.

> Should I use NSUserDefaults for data that stay even after app upgrade?

Only if your data is small.